# "sometime" and "sometimes"

Tags: grammaticality

I came across two sentences and wanted to check with you which one is correct:

> (1) Back then, I was trouble-making and rebellious sometime.
>   (2) Back then, I was trouble-making and rebellious sometimes.

Comment: Have you looked up _sometime_ and _sometimes_ in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still confused because in this case, I wanted to say that at some point in the past I was xxx. I don't know if "sometime" works here.

Comment: Not really. _Sometimes_ would mean 'on several occasions'. If you are only referring to one occasion, it's better to word it differently - 'there was a time when I was xxx', for example.

Comment: *I'll see you **sometime*** means I'll see you *at some unspecified future time*, with the strong implication that I'm only referring to a ***single*** future meeting. But *I'll see you **sometimes*** implies that I'll see you ***more than once*** in the future (just not very frequently).

Answer (score -1):

If your are asking specifically about "sometime/sometimes", the second is correct. It is clear the writer is referring to a pattern of repeated behaviour which and to multiple occasions, so "sometimes" is correct. If only one action is being referred to, then "sometime" could be correct, but even so its use is unusual - more usually it refers to some planned or future action: "I'll go to New York sometime".

The use of "trouble-making" is also rather non-standard. More usually you might say "Back then I caused trouble..." or "Back then I was a trouble maker..." or "Back then I was troublesome..."